# How to automatically change permalink from 000-111-222 to 000111222 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to change permalink mydomain.com/000-111-222 to mydomain.com/000111222 in WordPress

Please suggest, preference between editing WordPress code or .htaccess

Comment: Are you looking for a way to convert many permalinks at once? Do you want the old URLs to redirect to the new ones? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Please add the code in to your themes `functions.php`. It will solve the problem.

```
function generateSlug($slug)
{
$slug = strtolower($slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $slug); // kill entities
$slug = str_replace('.', '-', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9_-]/', '', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $slug);
$slug = trim($slug, '-');
return $slug;
}
remove_filter('sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes');
add_filter('sanitize_title','generateSlug');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
but I want to automatic change when I save a new post.

Comment: For this to work you have to set permalinks as post name through Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: Please note that this function will only change the permalink of the post which are going to make and not the posts which are already made. Try creating a new post.

Comment: dear @Anoop Asok,
thank you for your reply. I add this code to `functions.php`  and set permalinks as post name and creating a new post but noting happens.

Comment: I am sad that it did not help you. It works well here. Sorry :-(

Comment: Don't Worry @Anoop Asok, Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Welcome Polsin Kingket :-)